What is the history of the idea of conscience as a homunculus?
What is the historical origin of the mental categorization or anthropomorphization of conscience as a kind of semi-person distinct from, subordinate to, and constitutive of the self?
To clarify: as opposed to a kind of knowledge (conscience taken literally is just self-knowledge); and as opposed to a kind of external spiritual influence which may be bound up with the idea of self knowledge (e.g. Krishna or "Jesus living in my heart"), but is mainly considered to be a separate or higher mode of being, not a constituent part.
That is: the sense in which I can say, "My conscience made me think it was wrong" without just meaning that I knew it was wrong, or even "my conscience protested at my decision" without implying that I believe any exterior spiritual influence is in communication  with me.
Posting this here instead of on Psych since I think that references to works of philosophy, religion, or storytelling will be more useful for approximating the where and when of an idea's origins than speculative forensic psychoanalysis.

Socrates' "daemon" was similar to the voice of conscience: (1) an inner (divine) voice (auditive metaphor) (2) only forbidding him to do certain things (as far as I remember).

I know that in classical Chinese times there was a belief in several distinct "souls" (an earthy, 'heavy' one and a light one); it's a bit unclear sometimes what they mean by "神“ (spirit) which is yet another part of "mind" (and suggests sth divine). But it's very characteristic, imo, that ethical judgement is almost always associated just with "knowledge" (知, 智) or with "intelligence"(明 - literally: "light", so using a decidedly visual metaphor). The heart (心) is generally seen as the seat/organ of thinking and knowledge, btw.

(In other words, classical Chinese thought is remarkable because it has no body-mind dualism and it has no person-conscience dualism. It's a negative example for what you're looking for :) )

Richard Sorabji, "Moral conscience through the ages" (https://academic.oup.com/book/11348?login=false) traces "the voice of conscience" (syneidesis) back to 5th century BCE (Greek playwrights like Euripides; also Plato). Haven't read the book - but seems interesting. (And now I'd like to see some meurologicial research...)

St. Jerome added conscience (synderesis) to the structural theory of the soul, to join reason, spirit and desire of Plato's Chariot Allegory, although he and later scholastics tended to construe it as a "power" or "disposition" rather than a fully reified subagent, see Medieval Theories of Conscience. I am not sure that the language of daemons and inner voices unequivocally suggests the latter either, rather than metaphorical use and/or linguistic nominalization.

I suspect that the split of Latin conscientia into modern conscience and consciousness in the 17th century, together with Cartesian dualism that inspired the traditional "homunculus", played a role in ascribing quasi-agency to conscience, see Seventeenth-Century Theories of Consciousness. Possibly, the full crystallization of it only concluded with the Superego of Freud's psychoanalysis, see Lapsley-Stey on its genesis in his work.
